# Autoincrement verification sms code (otp || 2fa) in browser

Tags: javascript, html, auto-increment, autofill, two-factor-authentication

Is it possible to getting verification sms code from browser(javascript) application ( autoincrement || auto filling)?

There are article that on ios 12 safari appeared the function auto filling sms verification code (2fa). But i can't find description(html5 or javascript) how does this work?

**UPD**
it's work well in safari:

```
<input type="tel" id="single-factor-code-text-field" autocomplete="one-time-code">
```

Answer (score 1):

I was find apple documentation for this feature

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element

I did not try it yet. But i thing it works only with secret key from clipboard. When you you tap to sms with code, ios suggest you copy code to clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the iOS autofill for 2FA is a bit of a mystery. Apple haven't documented a particular way to ensure this works. I had a search around to try to see if there was a specific HTML attribute you could use to ensure the device tries to fill in with the code, but I couldn't find anything.

As far as I can tell, Safari runs some heuristics on your page and on incoming SMS messages and if a code is found in the SMS and the page appears to have an input for a code then it offers the autofill. If you are looking to ensure this works on your site, I recommend inspecting the HTML of another site that you have seen it work on and use similar names for the input field.